# MS Access VBA - Importing CSV Files - Upside-down "L"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a macro in Access which for all the files in a folder reformats and imports the data into Access tables. For most of these file it works perfectly, however for some it does not import anything. I have debugged the process and found that when these files are pulled into the recordset I have created to hold them as I reformat every character is broken up with an upsidedown "L":

[image: ScreenShot.png]

This is not in the file, not can I see it in any other view. If I set a watch on a variable and fill it with this string it interprets it as a space. Also these are not visible in the file if I open it in Excel or notepad...

Any idea what is causing this?

[Link to example file on Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VgDiw5VqWtuFFtI3FJYBJkwsV3FB6c7DoL5ZdgDb05E/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV files you are trying to import have apparently been saved with Unicode encoding (specifically, UTF16-LE) and Access is trying to read them as though they were encoded as "ANSI" (Windows-1252), so

- the first two "funny characters" are the Byte Order Mark (BOM), 0xFFFE, which Access interprets as `ÿþ`, and
- the interspersed "upside-down 'L'" characters are representations of the 0x00 high-order bytes of each Unicode character

[image: HexEdit.png]

This can happen if you try to import a CSV file without an Import Specification, because in that case Access will "guess" at the structure of the file and assume things like

- the encoding ("Code Page") is "ANSI" (or sometimes "OEM"),
- the Field Delimiter is `,`,
- the Text Qualifier is `"` (or perhaps `{none}`)

The solution is to create a saved Import Specification and supply its name as the second argument to the `DoCmd.TransferText` method that performs the import. For details on creating a saved Import Specification see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24282381/2144390).