# TransferText incorrectly imports strings like "FS###" as Currency

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am using the VBA `DoCmd.TransferText` command to import data from a CSV text file into a new table in my Access database. I have run into an issue where the text data in the first three columns in some of the files is imported as currency. I cannot figure out what is happening.

[Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvQ-yS4VyT-NjgoMsUSThnPiohOn) is a test database along with one CSV that imports correctly (VollintineLines.csv) ...

```
PipeID,UpstreamMH,DownstreamMH,Diameter,GISLength,Status
WS010353S,WS010353,WS010163,36,227.1984614,Fully Surveyed as Phase Work
WS011155S,WS011155,WS011154,8,418.5435318,Not Surveyed
WS011154S,WS011154,WS011153,8,303.9618911,Fully Surveyed as Phase Work
```

... and one that doesn't (CourtLines.csv).

```
PipeID,UpstreamMH,DownstreamMH,Diameter,GISLength,Status
FS020628S,FS020628,FS020462,10,278.72,Not Surveyed
FS020463S-1,FS020463,FS020462,12,248.39,Not Surveyed
FS020216S,FS020216,FS020215,12,227.53,Fully Surveyed as Phase Work
```

(Please ignore the unnamed objects in the database, it was just to figure out what is going on here and I didn't bother naming things.)

Here is the import code, you have to enable the Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library Reference.

```vbs
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim Path As FileDialog
Dim FileName As Variant
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.Hourglass True
Set Path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With Path
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select your File"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    If .Show = -1 Then

        For Each FileName In .SelectedItems
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "TempPipeData", FileName, True
        Next FileName

    Else
        MsgBox "No File Selected to Import."
    End If

    End With
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

Comment: The ZIP file of your test database is missing the file name of your Access DB!!

Comment: It is now fixed, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have apparently encountered a rather obscure bug affecting `TransferText` calls that do not use an Import Specification. (It is also discussed on another site [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1751559).)

Workarounds include:

1. Use an Import Specification as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24282381/2144390).
2. Create the table first, specifying the desired column types (`Text` in this case), and then import from the CSV file into the existing (empty) table.
3. If neither of the above options is desirable, then you could use COM Automation to

   - launch an instance of Excel,
   - have Excel open the CSV file,
   - save it to XLS or XLSX,
   - use `TransferSpreadsheet` in Access VBA to import the Excel data, then
   - delete the temporary XLS[X] file.

Comment: Thank you, going with #2 and just clearing the table after the import instead of deleting it worked.

Also, thank you for editing my original post to make it clearer.